# Rails: date format in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I am using a select tag to make users select a month/year.

**In my controller:**

```
@months = ((Date.new(2017).beginning_of_year..Date.today.end_of_year).select { |day| day.mday == 1 })
```

**In my from:**

```
<%= f.select :month, @months %>
```

Which gives me a dropdown with dates like **2017-01-01**, **2017-02-01**, **2017-03-01** etc.

However in the dropdown I want **January 2017**, **February 2017**, **March 2017** etc.

How can I achieve that? I tried strftime in the select tag but it does not work.

Comment: This is what I get when I run your controller code in irb `[Sun, 01 Jan 2017, Wed, 01 Feb 2017, Wed, 01 Mar 2017, Sat, 01 Apr 2017, Mon, 01 May 2017, Thu, 01 Jun 2017, Sat, 01 Jul 2017, Tue, 01 Aug 2017, Fri, 01 Sep 2017, Sun, 01 Oct 2017, Wed, 01 Nov 2017, Fri, 01 Dec 2017]
` Have you glanced at the `date_select` method? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: The same is true if I print the array. However, this is not true in the select tag. I do not want to use date_select because it gives me separate select fields for year and month. I want both in one field.

Answer (score 0):

When you assing `@months`, you get a array:

```
@months = ((Date.new(2017).beginning_of_year..Date.today.end_of_year).select { |day| day.mday == 1 })
 => [Sun, 01 Jan 2017, Wed, 01 Feb 2017, Wed, 01 Mar 2017, Sat, 01 Apr 2017, Mon, 01 May 2017, Thu, 01 Jun 2017, Sat, 01 Jul 2017, Tue, 01 Aug 2017, Fri, 01 Sep 2017, Sun, 01 Oct 2017, Wed, 01 Nov 2017, Fri, 01 Dec 2017]
```

You then can create a new array with the dates in the format that you need, using `strftime`:

```
@monthFormat = []  #must create the array first
@months.each { |month| @monthFormat << month.strftime("%B, %Y") }
```

And then you have an array just like the original, but with the format:

```
@monthFormat.each { |monthFormat| puts monthFormat }
    January, 2017
    February, 2017
    March, 2017
    April, 2017
    May, 2017
    June, 2017
    July, 2017
    August, 2017
    September, 2017
    October, 2017
    November, 2017
    December, 2017
     => ["January, 2017", "February, 2017", "March, 2017", "April, 2017", "May, 2017", "June, 2017", "July, 2017", "August, 2017", "September, 2017", "October, 2017", "November, 2017", "December, 2017"]
```

Then you can put load your dropdown with `@monthFormat`, but select must be the same `@month`:

```
<%= f.select :month, @month %>
```

And it should work the same as with `@month`.

Here you have the [complete list of formats](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) strftime.

Comment: It works for the select tag but on submit no date is saved.

Comment: I think it migth be the `@monthFormat` that it's not working on the form, let me edit